# Correct way to read input stream android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a piece of code below that is to receive an input stream from a socket on Android. It works fine, but when the phone goes to sleep, my logger goes crazy printing out that it received `""`.

From my debugging it means that my `if` statement in the whole loop is not sufficient?

```
//Global variable declaration
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];   

 while (mRun) {
            int len = in.read(buffer);
            input = "";

            if (buffer != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    input += (char) buffer[i];
                }
                // call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                mMessageListener.messageReceived(input);
                System.out.println("Recieved: " + input);
            }
            input = "";
        }
```

That is my code that runs in the `while`. Now, I am sure I am not testing a correct condition in my :
    `if (buffer != null && mMessageListener != null)`
code.

What else could I test / what could I be testing that is incorrect?

Obviously after the `while` has run once, the buffer is not == null and then I am assuming that when the phone goes to sleep (screen goes black) `mMessageListener` becomes non null ?

Thanks

Comment: Have You tried to run this code as a Service? Of course, if You want it to be executed even when application is being closed/paused due some reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the `len` variable for being greater than 0, read method will return -1 when reaches end of stream so:

```
if (len>0 && buffer != null && mMessageListener != null)
```

Comment: Thanks For the help, that seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) You shouldn't use + operator to join multiple Strings, it's very slow, use StringBuilder instead.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       sb.append((char)buffer[i]);
    }

    String input = sb.toString();
```

Or, this may be even faster if you joining by single characters:

```
    char[] inputChars = new char[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       inputChars[i] = (char)buffer[i];
    }

    String input = new String(inputChars);
```

There's shorter way to achieve this effect..

```
    String input = new String(buffer);
```

2) I'm not sure, but buffer will never become null in this case, so != null statement is pointless. Length can be 0 if there's no data readed, so check if len != 0.

Comment: Your second point is not correct. read will return -1 in the case it reaches the end of stream, not 0.

Comment: StringBuilder will be used by the JVM under the covers automatically. It's safe to add strings.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Well, there's a number of mean looking statements there. Is that all the code? How do you expect things to become `null` or spawn to life on their own?

If you want to consume an InputStream, the easiest way is to use a `Scanner`:

```
String text = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

This says "scan the input stream `in` until the end is found". You may use another delimiter to split it into several parts.

Comment: no that is not all the code, i just didn't want to past all of the code as i predicted this was the area of concern. If the rest of the code is needed, i can provide it :)